# python's 'return' returns only first iteration result of the loop

Tags: python

```
def intersect(seq,seq1):
    res = []
    for x in seq:
        if x in seq1:
            res.append(x)
            return res
```

`return res` only returns `['s']` but with `seq="spam"` and `seq1="scam"` in the function call, why is it not returning `['s','a','m']`?

Answer (score 3):

Because the line

```
return res
```

is not in the correct position (in other words, it has *bad indentation*). It should be outside the `for` loop, so your program first *finishes* the loop and then returns the result:

```
def intersect(seq, seq1):
    res = []
    for x in seq:
        if x in seq1:
            res.append(x)
    return res
```

**Note:** Remember that indentation is extremely important in Python, because it's used to determine the grouping of statements.

Answer (score 1):

Your `return res` indentation is wrong. It should be:

```
def intersect(seq,seq1):
    res=[]
    for x in seq:
        if x in seq1:
            res.append(x)
    return res

>>> intersect('scam','spam')
['s','a','m']
```

What you were doing earlier was that you were appending one value and then returning it. You want to return `res` when you have appended `all` your values. This happens **after** the `for` loop and that is when you put the `return res` line. Therefore, it should have the same indentation as the `for` statement.

Comment: I am new to Python as well to stackoverflow, Both seem Magic :-) Thanks for your quick response